# Getting started with Urban Airship in iOS

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

I am trying to add Urban Airship to my iOS project. I am using the lastest version (1.2.0) and am following the instructions here: 
https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+iOS%3A+Push

The instructions seem pretty clear in general. There seems to be no mention though of what files I'm supposed to include in my import statements.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:  [UAirship.h](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/blob/master/Airship/Library/AirshipLib/UAirship.h)

Comment: This as well, #import "UAAnalytics.h"

Answer (score 0):

And also this one:

## import "UAPush.h"